# Azure Redis Master-Slave

Tags: azure-redis-cache

Is it possible to implement Master-Slave Feature which is provided as an Normal Redis Feature in Azure Redis too?

As per my understanding internal master-slave is automatically implemented in Standard Pricing Tier,but can we achieve specifying our own masster-slave redis instances?

Answer (score 1):

As a managed service, Azure Redis will control the master-slave configuration. The service will also control when to promote slave (and demote master) as necessary. Being able to manually set the master-slave configuration is not supported. Additionally, traffic to the Redis endpoint ports (6379 or 6380) will automatically be directed the current master instance. By using the managed Redis service, Azure offers an [SLA](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/cache/v1_0/) which covers connectivity to these cache endpoints.

If you are self-hosting Redis in your own Virtual Machines, the master-slave configuration would be under your control, however this does not come with the same support and SLA as using Azure Redis instances.